# Crash when setting AudioKit output node on iPhone 5s

Tags: audiokit

I get a consistent crash whenever I set AudioKit output to a mixer node. The crash happens on an iPhone 5s running iOS 10.3.3, but NOT on an iPhone 7 running iOS 11.3.

The code I'm running (setting up a recording view):

```
mic = AKMicrophone()
mic.stop()
fft = AKFFTTap.init(mic)
micMixer = AKMixer(mic)
micBooster = AKBooster(micMixer)
micBooster.gain = 0
do {
            recorder = try AKNodeRecorder(node: micMixer)

            if let file = recorder.audioFile {
                player = try AKAudioPlayer(file: file)
                player.looping = false
                player.completionHandler = playingEnded
            }
            mainMixer = AKMixer(player, micBooster)
            AudioKit.output = mainMixer //THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES!
        }
        catch {
            //debug prints here don't get printed
            throw error
        }
```

The catch block is never called, an error is not thrown.

Crash details in logs:

ERROR: [0x1b12c0b40] >avae> AVAudioIONodeImpl.mm:466: EnableBus_block_invoke: error -10849
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error -10849'

Any help or information would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can’t create a player with a file that is being recorded.

Comment: That's not it, since this works on another device. Plus, the player initialization is the same as in the recorder demo here: http://audiokit.io/examples/RecorderDemo/

Comment: Does the player play on the other device?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the cause, but I was starting the AudioKit engine in another piece of code before that I missed. When I moved the AudioKit.start() call after the AudioKit.output = .... call, it doesn't crash.